# GZipStream Compress/Decompress

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, filestream

Добрый вечер. Пытаюсь решить задачку на сжатие/разжатие файла с помощью GZipStream. Из условий - эффективная работа в многопроцессорной среде и работа с большими файлами(превышающими размер оперативной памяти на компьютере).
Для ее решения решил использовать паттерн Consumer-Producer.
Читаю файл в очередь попутно разбивая его на блоки:

```
public void ReadDataFromFile(string fileName)
        {
            using (Stream sourceFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {               
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[dataBlockSize];
                    int nRead = sourceFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);                    
                    if (nRead > 0)
                    {                       
                        DataBlock block = new DataBlock(buffer, nRead);                        
                        sourceQueue.Enqueue(block);
                        Console.WriteLine("Produce: " + block.Size);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }                    
                }                
            }
```

Запускаем обработчик (в нем идет считывание-сжатие а потом запись в другую очередь, в которой хранятся сжатые блоки.

```
public void TaskHandler()
        {
            while (sourceQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                DataBlock sourceBlock = sourceQueue.Dequeue();
                DataBlock compressedBlock = Compress(sourceBlock);
                writeQueue.Enqueue(compressedBlock);                
            }
        }
```

Метод для сжатия

```
 public DataBlock Compress(DataBlock block)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    gzip.Write(block.Data, 0, block.Size);
                }

                block.Data = memory.ToArray();                
                block.Size = block.Data.Length;
                return block;
            }
        }
```

И собственно говоря метод записи в файл

```
public void WriteDataToFile(string fileName)
        {
            using (Stream newFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                while (writeQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataBlock block = writeQueue.Dequeue();
                    newFileStream.Write(block.Data, 0, block.Data.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Write " + block.Size);
                }
            }
        }
```

Проблема в следующем - программа отрабатывает и сжимает файл, и я могу открыть его винраром и все будет нормально, но если я пробую сделать Decompress с помощью GZipStream - он ругается на "магическое число". Я читал что надо как-то в начало каждого сжатого блока добавить длину этого блока, и потом исходя из этого разжимать его - но у меня почему-то при разжатии получался не читаемый файл.

Answer (score 2):

Мне жаль вас расстраивать, но вы делаете ненужное.

"Эффективная работа в многопроцессорной среде" при сжатии/распаковке итак реализована в внутренних классах пространства System.IO.Compression. Да, там использутся обычные треды, а не новомодные "асинхронные задачи", но разницы никакой нет - сжатие/распаковка происходят в оптимальном количестве тредов, и нагрузка итак распределяется на все имеющиеся процессоры.

А "работа с большими файлами(превышающими размер оперативной памяти на компьютере)" обеспечивается концепцией потоков(Stream'ом) - почти все потоки предназначены для поточной обработки данных. Память они используют минимально, только для целей буферизации(за исключением MemoryStream). Просто оберните свой FileStream(или NetworkStream, или любой другой поток) непосредственно в GzipStream, и сможете сжимать/расжимать буквально бесконечные обьемы данных, с минимальным расходом памяти, и без утечек её со временем.

Не стоит недоценивать библиотеку .NET Framework в плане различных оптимизаций - её писали далеко не глупые люди.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня возникает тогда еще вопрос - к примеру в данной книге автор делает сжатие с помощью ThreadPool https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=731 . Или это тоже не правильно? А до этого он в статье при сжатии файлов вообще указывал "размер сжатого блока" в начале. Хотя стоит отметить что в книге "псевдо код" и возможно что gzipstream уже сам делает данные действия без нас в .NET?